# how to ouput sed/samtools result into new directory

Tags: sed, samtools

I have the following sed command that change the chromosome name:

```
for file in /myoldpath/*.bam; do filename=`echo $file | cut -d "." -f 1`; samtools view -H $file | sed -e 's/SN:\([0-9XY]\)/SN:chr\1/' -e 's/SN:MT/SN:chrM/' | samtools reheader - $file > /mynewpath/${filename}_chr.bam; done
```

My quesion is how to insert the result in a new path while keeping the variable $filename as part of every new file name? It always inserts the result in /myoldpath/ or leterally "filename.chr.bam" in the /mynewpath/.
am i missing something in the syntax of that part `$file > /mynewpath/${filename}_chr.bam`?

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change *filename=echo $file | cut -d "." -f 1;* to *filename=$(echo $file| rev| cut -d "/" -f 1|rev|cut -d "." -f1 );*

Comment: Thank you @lurii for the response. I tried this one but i got an output in the form of "_chr_bam". here is what i tried: `for file in /myoldpath/*.bam; do filename=$(echo $file | cut -d "." -f 1); samtools view -H $file | sed -e 's/SN:([0-9XY])/SN:chr\1/' -e 's/SN:MT/SN:chrM/' | samtools reheader - $file > /mynewpath/${filename}_chr.bam; done`

Comment: what is a file name look like if you change your command to /mynewpath/${file}_chr.bam ?

Comment: you can try this filename=$(echo $file| rev| cut -d "/" -f 1|rev|cut -d "." -f1 );